# Dozer: Mapping fields for specific subclasses

Tags: java, soap, dozer

The situation is this:

On the side of the domain we have a superclass let's call it Plant
and two subclasses Vegestable and DecorativePlant.

```
public abstract class Plant {

    private String name;
    @Mapping("elementValue.carbonValue")
    private int carbonValue;
    @Mapping("elementValue.oxygenValue")
    private int oxygenValue;

}

public abstract class Vegestable extends Plant {

    private int nutritionValue;
}

public abstract class DecorativePlant extends Plant {

    private int rating;
}
```

now on the side of our soap api we have simular objects. The main difference
would probably be that we don't want the decorative plant on the soap-side to have

```
public class Vegestable {

    private int nutrition;
    private ElementValue elementValue;
}

public class DecorativePlant {

    private int rating;
}

public class ElementValue {
    private int carbonValue;
    private int oxygenValue;
}
```

So now I was wondering if it is possible to specify that Dozer only maps the fields carbonValue and oxygenValue for subclasses of Vegestable and not for subclasses of DecorativePlant? If it's possible in Dozer than I won't have to actually alter my classes on the domain level and basically place the carbonValue and oxygenValue in both subclasses and than Dozer won't do the mapping for DecorativePlant. (A side from the @Mapping annotation I'm doing all my mapping in a mappings.xml file.)

Big thanks in advance!